# InputMismatchException in Scanner.nextBoolean()

Tags: java

I am running this code to get 3 values: an **integer**, a **string** and a **boolean** from the user and print it in separate lines.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Practice {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int a;
    String b;
    boolean c;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    a = scanner.nextInt();
    b = scanner.nextLine();
    c = scanner.nextBoolean();

    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(c);

   }
}
```

I am trying to give input like this:

```
1
hello world
true
```

and am getting this error after writing the second line of input

Comment: hello welcome to stackoverflow what does the error showed while you writing the second line of input? my guess is because the newline character got scan into your variable `b`, thats happened because `nextInt()` does not scan the newline character so your "enter" will be scanned to variable `b`, for more detailed answer check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

Answer (score 0):

`next()` can read the input only till the space. It can't read two words separated by a space. Also, `next()` places the cursor in the same line after reading the input.

`nextLine()` reads input including space between the words (that is, it reads till the end of line \n). Once the input is read, `nextLine()` positions the cursor in the next line.

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a = scan.nextInt();
    String b = scan.next();
    boolean c = scan.nextBoolean();

    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so basically you can use next() instead of nextLine() or reorder if you really need to use nextLine()

```
b = scanner.nextLine();
a = scanner.nextInt();
c = scanner.nextBoolean();
```